# Redirect to external url after order creation

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, redirect-url

I am making a payment gateway and I need to redirect from the invoice page to an external url. 
Basically when an order is created at Magento I create an order in a 3rd party app with curl, then I get unique ID from that order which is used to redirect to an external invoice page.

The question is how do i make that external redirect? Most logical solution seems to override the checkout controller and in that controller I would call my model, model returns that unique ID and I make redirect to the invoice page.

Problem is I can't understand how to override the checkout controller.

Comment: Do I understand it correct that you want to redirect away from Magento to another source? At which point in the checkout do you want to redirect exactly?

Comment: i guess you creat your own payment method? If this is true, you can override the method `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` in your Payment model and return your custom URL.

Comment: i found this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2241[](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2241) they say you should implement the redirection client-side just have a look at the paypal express implementation

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no explicitly defined extension point for your scenario. However, you can override the default behavior by creating a [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success::execute` method.